# how to select unique attribute of div in cypress

Tags: attributes, cypress

How do I select the unique attribute of div in Cypress? In my case, I want to get ***data-testid***

```
<div id="Dropdown78" 
     class="ms-Dropdown-title" 
     data-testid= "busnum_drop"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to validate that the attribute `data-testid` has a value busnum_drop ?

Comment: I want to select "data-testid" in cypress and click on it. for example if i wan to select id of that <div> element I would do cy.get("#Dropdown78").click(). Now how can I select  "data-testid" and click on it. Hope explained you clearly

Comment: I have added the an answer, can you check if it works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
cy.get('#Dropdown78').click()
cy.get('[data-testid="busnum_drop"]').click()
```